# Silicon Valley Finale: P = NP?

Tags: silicon-valley

Is it correct that the Pied Piper Middle-Out Neural Network determined that [P = NP?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem) in the *Sillicon Valley* finale?

Gilfoyle's link was somewhat garbled, but I recall he noted that it had solved a very difficult problem in "polynomial time".

(I just want to make sure I understand the meaning of the episode, which seems to be they solved what is likely to be the most materially significant outstanding mathematics problem known to humans, and, rather than publishing, sabotaged their company and covered it up.)

Answer (score 5):

Here is what Gilfoyle actually said,

> GILFOYLE: Our internal messaging, based on HooliChat, uses a weak encryption standard known as P-256. Whether Richard believes it or not, our network cracked it.
>
> MONICA: Who allowed it to do that?
>
> GILFOYLE: We did, when we gave it one job. To make itself more efficient. It developed a general solution to discrete log in polynomial time.
>
> RICHARD: What ?

The discrete logarithm problem is considered to be computationally intractable. That is, no efficient classical algorithm is known for computing discrete logarithms in general. ([Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm))

It is one of the unsolved problems in Computer Science. In my current understanding this problem is different from P=NP.

So what they are trying to depict is that, they were able to compute discrete logarithm in polynomial time using classical computers as their AI + Middle-Out Algorithm is so much efficient at improving each other.

In layman's term, they developed an computer program such that it solves most difficult problems.